# Multiple data sources with different timeintervalls in the same table

Tags: mysql

I have this situation:

Until recently I had a table in my db which got updated through a python script (running as a cronjob). 
I've handled this the following way (commands in mysqldb-python):

```
DROP TABLE tmp IF EXISTS
CREATE TABLE tmp LIKE original
INSERT INTO tmp...
DROP TABLE original
ALTER TABLE tmp RENAME TO original
```

Now I have 2 sources of data for the same table. The table is going to be updated from the 2 sources in different timeintervalls (source 1 each 'x minutes', source 2 each 'y minutes'). I can't create a tmp table and insert the data there because the data from the other source isn't going to be included. I thought about adding a field `Source`to the table and then in the scripts:

```
DELETE FROM original WHERE Source = 'currentsource'
INSERT INTO original ...
```

Problem with this method is that the ID AUTO_INCREMENT doesn't reset. I don't particularly want to check for the current max ID and set the increment if there's a better solution.

Which solution would you suggest?

Comment: *ID AUTO_INCREMENT doesn't work anymore.* - why do you think so?

Comment: @splash58 That was a terrible formulation. Edited the post.

Comment: why can't you just insert directly into original? Why does the auto-increment value matter?

Comment: @ADyson Well as you see from the second portion of code that's what I'm doing. I have to delete the former entries and the insert the new ones. Problem is: The ID values grow indefinitely this way. I know I could technically change ID to a BigInt but is that really the proper "solution" for that?

Comment: @R6D1H2 there's no real reason why not IMHO. If you know you're going to need a huge number of rows, then use a data type, such as bigint, which can accomodate that. It's what those values are there for. I've dealt with tables in enterprise systems with so many rows that it was necessary to use large integers for IDs. The only other way really is to see if you can update the existing rows instead of deleting, but I realise that may not be practical

Comment: @ADyson Ok thanks for the info. It just seems more as a workaround than a solution to me but I guess you're right and it doesn't really matter. Yes checking for update instead of delete is not really an option.